# Using boost-odeint within MPI context without using mpi_state results in different time steps for adaptive stepper

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, odeint, petsc

I'm trying to upgrade an existing code which uses odeint to be able to use MPI for calculating the right hand side function more efficiently. It is possible to combine boost::odeint with MPI based on the documentation, but that would require changing the `state_type` of the solver to `mpi_state`, something I would like to avoid to preserve backwards compatibility.
Therefore, I intended to split the vectors into parts before handing them over to the odeint-function (without telling the function that it is operating in an MPI context), and combine them in the RHS-function again. A short demonstration function for that (I am using PETSc for the vector-communication) is shown below:

```
struct Petsc_RHS_state {
    Petsc_RHS_state(MPI_Comm &communicator, const int global_size) : communicator(communicator) {
        VecCreate(communicator, &local_vec);
        VecSetSizes(local_vec, PETSC_DECIDE, global_size);
        VecSetFromOptions(local_vec);
        VecZeroEntries(local_vec);
        VecAssemblyBegin(local_vec);
        VecAssemblyEnd(local_vec);

        VecCreate(communicator, &scaling_vec);
        VecSetSizes(scaling_vec, PETSC_DECIDE, global_size);
        VecSetFromOptions(scaling_vec);
        PetscScalar set_val = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < global_size; ++i)
            VecSetValues(scaling_vec, 1, &i, &set_val, INSERT_VALUES);
        VecAssemblyBegin(scaling_vec);
        VecAssemblyEnd(scaling_vec);

        MatCreateDense(communicator, PETSC_DECIDE, PETSC_DECIDE, global_size, global_size, NULL, &diagonal_mat);
        MatSetFromOptions(diagonal_mat);
        MatZeroEntries(diagonal_mat);
        MatAssemblyBegin(diagonal_mat, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
        MatAssemblyEnd(diagonal_mat, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
    }

    ~Petsc_RHS_state(){
        VecDestroy(&local_vec);
        VecDestroy(&scaling_vec);
    };

    void operator()(const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, double t) const {
        std::cout << t << '\n';
        const size_t M = x.size();
        PetscScalar *local_ptr;
        VecGetArray(local_vec, &local_ptr);
        for(size_t m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
            *(local_ptr + m) = x[m];
        }
        VecRestoreArray(local_vec, &local_ptr);
        VecPointwiseMult(local_vec, scaling_vec, local_vec);
        MatDiagonalScale(diagonal_mat, NULL, local_vec);
        VecGetArray(local_vec, &local_ptr);
        for(size_t m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
            *(local_ptr + m) = calculation_function(*(local_ptr + m), t);
        }
        for(size_t m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
            dxdt[m] = *(local_ptr + m);
        }
        VecRestoreArray(local_vec, &local_ptr);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T calculation_function (const T &x, const double t) const {
        return 3. / (2 * t * t) + x / (2 * t);
    }

    MPI_Comm communicator;
    Vec local_vec, scaling_vec;
    Mat diagonal_mat;
};
 
void test_ts_arma_with_pure_petsc_preconfigured (const size_t matrix_size_rows, const size_t matrix_size_cols,
                                                 const arma::cx_colvec &initial_condition_vec,
                                                 arma::cx_colvec &solution_vec,
                                                 const double dt,
                                                 const double t_min, const double t_max) {
    PetscMPIInt rank, size;

    MPI_Comm_size(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    boost::mpi::communicator boost_comm(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, boost::mpi::comm_attach);

    state_type x_initial = arma::conv_to<value_type>::from(initial_condition_vec);

    Mat input_mat;
    MatCreateDense(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, PETSC_DECIDE, PETSC_DECIDE, matrix_size_rows, matrix_size_cols, NULL, &input_mat);
    MatZeroEntries(input_mat);
    MatAssemblyBegin(input_mat, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
    MatAssemblyEnd(input_mat, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);

    PetscInt local_cols, global_cols, local_rows, global_rows;
    PetscInt first_row, last_row;
    MatGetLocalSize(input_mat, &local_rows, &local_cols);
    MatGetSize(input_mat, &global_rows, &global_cols);
    MatGetOwnershipRange(input_mat, &first_row, &last_row);

    state_type x_split((last_row - first_row) * global_cols);

    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has a total size of " << matrix_size_rows << ", " << matrix_size_cols << '\n';
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has an initial size of " << initial_condition_vec.n_elem << '\n';
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has a local matrix size of " << local_rows << ", " << local_cols << '\n';
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has a global matrix size of " << global_rows << ", " << global_cols << '\n';
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has rows from " << first_row << " to " << last_row << '\n';
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " has a vector size of " << x_split.size() << '\n';

    const PetscScalar *read_ptr;
    MatDenseGetArrayRead (input_mat, &read_ptr);
    for(int j = 0; j < global_cols; ++j) {
        for(int i = 0; i < last_row - first_row; ++i) {
            const int cur_pos = i + j * (last_row - first_row);
            x_split[cur_pos] = *(read_ptr + cur_pos);
        }
    }
    MatDenseRestoreArrayRead (input_mat, &read_ptr);

    runge_kutta4<state_type> stepper;

    Petsc_RHS_state local_calculator(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, matrix_size_cols * matrix_size_rows);

        integrate_adaptive(bulirsch_stoer<state_type>(1e-8, 1e-6),
                   local_calculator,
                   x_split,
                   t_min,
                   t_max,
                   dt);

    PetscScalar *write_ptr;
    MatDenseGetArrayWrite (input_mat, &write_ptr);
    for(int j = 0; j < global_cols; ++j) {
        for(int i = 0; i < last_row - first_row; ++i) {
            const int cur_pos = i + j * (last_row - first_row);
            *(write_ptr + cur_pos) = x_split[cur_pos];
        }
    }
    MatDenseRestoreArrayWrite (input_mat, &write_ptr);

    MatView(input_mat, PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);

    Mat local_mat;
    MatCreateRedundantMatrix(input_mat, size, MPI_COMM_NULL, MAT_INITIAL_MATRIX, &local_mat);
    MatAssemblyBegin(local_mat, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
    MatAssemblyEnd(local_mat, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
    //MatGetValues(local_mat, Nradius, vector_indices_radius.memptr(), Nomega, vector_indices_omega.memptr(), in_mat.memptr());
    const PetscScalar *local_mat_read_ptr;
    MatDenseGetArrayRead(local_mat, &local_mat_read_ptr);
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)matrix_size_cols; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)matrix_size_rows; ++j) {
            const PetscInt cur_pos = j + i * matrix_size_cols;
            x_initial[cur_pos] = *(local_mat_read_ptr + cur_pos);
        }
    }
    MatDenseRestoreArrayRead(local_mat, &local_mat_read_ptr);
    MatDestroy(&local_mat);

    MPI_Bcast(x_initial.data(), 2 * x_initial.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, PETSC_COMM_WORLD);

    solution_vec = arma::conv_to<arma::cx_colvec>::from(x_initial);
    MatDestroy(&input_mat);
}
```

This works fine for small test programs, but now I encountered the problem that the time step can vary between the different threads by a small amount. As example:

```
Step number    Rank    Time step
n              1       0.00025
n              0       0.00025//Ok
n + 1          1       0.00051152
n + 1          0       0.000511523//Not ok
```

Is there a communication problem between the different threads for odeint, or is something else going wrong here? And is the approach possible at all, or should I rely on a different approach?

Comment: @HristoIliev: I just checked, yes, that is correct.  I just rechecked my production code, and I am using an adaptive stepper there, instead of a fixed-size stepper. I'll update the question accordingly

Comment: Using an adaptive integration scheme when each rank sees only the change in its own portion of the solution vector is probably not what you want to do.